# SAMBA server does not show up as media system but is accessible

Tags: networking, server, samba, file-sharing

My SAMBA server does not show up as a media system.  I'd like it to show up as a media server so that I can access it from my TV and my PS4. It's running on a machine running Ubuntu. I can access the SAMBA server by looking up the IP on a Windows PC.

How do I make it so my SAMBA shows up as a MEDIA player?

Note: My workgroup is WORKGROUP

Comment: Samba is not a media server. You need something like DLNA.

Comment: I looked into it a bit and I think you're right. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samba is not a media server. It is a file server used mostly for Windows.

You need to install some real media server to be able to use it the way you want.